# How to convert List<Object> to byte array using java or Android?

Tags: android, list, nullpointerexception, arrays

im developing a app in Android. in this project im using a List of Objects and i need to convert the list object in byte array. but there is a null pointer exception shown in logcat? here is my coading.

```
class MyContact
{
    String Name;
    Bitmap Image;
    String Number;

    public MyContact(String cName, String cNumber, Bitmap cImage) {

        Name    = cName;
        Number  = cNumber;
        Image   = cImage;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public Bitmap getImage() {
        return Image;
    }

    public void setImage(Bitmap image) {
        Image = image;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return Number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        Number = number;
    }
}



List<MyContact> list = new ArrayList<MyContact>();
```

I added some values to the List object, using

```
MyContact contactObj = new MyContact(name, phoneNo, photo);
 list.add(contactObj);

bla bla bla ....
```

and i need store the entire list object into the Android Mobiles local file. i used ,

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput( fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 fos.write(toByteArray(MyTrackList));   // null pointer error occured here
 fos.close();
```

here is a byte array conversion coding.

```
public static byte[] toByteArray (Object obj)
    {
      byte[] bytes = null;
      ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      try {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos); 
        oos.writeObject(obj);
        oos.flush(); 
        oos.close(); 
        bos.close();
        bytes = bos.toByteArray ();
      }
      catch (IOException ex) {
        //TODO: Handle the exception
      }
      return bytes;
    }
```

but returns null pointer exception in the line of above i marked in comment
 how can i resolve this problem. any suggestion? thanks in advance....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  catch (IOException ex) {
    //TODO: Handle the exception
  }
```

There is your problem: If there is an IOException, your method will just return null and not tell you about it.

Do not catch the exception, change the method to `throws IOException` (since there is nothing you can do at that point anyway) and then find out what caused it.

Most likely it is because your `MyContact` class does not implement `Serializable`, so that it cannot be written to an ObjectOutputStream.

Also, performance and memory-usage can be improved by not having that intermediate byte array and connecting the ObjectOutputStream directly to the FileOutputStream instead.

Comment: but i already added the IOException in the catch block. i didn't add this coding in the post.

Comment: don't catch the IOException. Otherwise you will just be left in the dark about this error (with a meaningless NullPointerException). You need to make your class serializable.

Answer (score 0):

The possible problem is nicely pointed out by @Thilo. Can you post the Logcat output please?

[ Suggestion :

I usually recommend using JSON/XML serialization as Android SDK has support for some really nice JSON/XML(DOM/SAX/XML pull) implementations.

- They make your local files readable, portable.
- And you can even transfer the files over the network, and store remotely too.

Hope this helps, Cheers!
]